# How to insert from one table to another from trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

So i have an after insert trigger to insert some data into a temp table, and i want to add to the end of the trigger the ability to insert the rows from the temp table back to the original table. This is a workaround for the mutating tables error. Thanks for the help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER podium_core.trigger_field_tag_sync
AFTER INSERT 
    ON podium_core.pd_field_tag
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        insert into podium_core.pd_field_tag_temp
        (   field_nid,
            tag,
            version,
            modifiedby,
            createdby)
        select distinct FOO.field_nid, :NEW.tag,0, 'trigger','trigger'
        from    
        (select child_field_nid as field_nid 
            from podium_core.pd_field_pc_rel 
            where parent_field_nid = :NEW.field_nid) FOO

        where :NEW.createdby <> 'trigger';

        delete from podium_core.pd_field_tag t1
            where (t1.nid, t1.tag, t1.field_nid) in
                    (select t2.nid, t2.tag, t2.field_nid
                        from podium_core.pd_field_tag t2
                     where t1.nid < t2.nid
                        and t1.tag = t2.tag
                        and t1.field_nid = t2.field_nid);
    END;
    /
```

Here is the temp table

```
create table podium_core.field_tag_temp
            (NID NUMBER NOT NULL,
                ENTITY_NID NUMBER NOT NULL,
                TAG VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
                CREATED_TTZ TIMESTAMP(6) NULL,
                MODIFIED_TTZ TIMESTAMP(6) NULL,
                VERSION NUMBER NULL,
                MODIFIEDBY VARCHAR(512) NULL,
                CREATEDBY VARCHAR(512) NULL,
                IS_EXTERNAL NUMBER(1) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: I assume when you tried adding the `insert` that you got the mutating trigger error, right?  This is probably something that you shouldn't be using a trigger to solve.  If you must use a trigger, you'd probably need multiple triggers (row- and statement-level) or a compound trigger with multiple sections (assuming a recent Oracle version).

Comment: Yeah so you hit the nail on the head.. oracle version is 12c. Using a trigger seems like the easiest option, what would be some alternate ways to solve this?

Comment: The simple answer would be to have a stored procedure that implements whatever logic you want and then have the application call the procedure for any data manipulation rather than doing DML directly on the table

Comment: Yeah..... that would be an easier solution but I need it to trigger every time I do an insert, therefore using a trigger is the only option for me I think

Comment: @Patryk100 would `Before INSERt` instead `AFTER INSERt` works ?

Comment: I think i still would be getting the mutating table problem